# Bitwise shift operator in Java: syntax error with "=>>"?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I'm writing some code to calculate the number of 1s appeared in the 2's complement format of an integer. However, when I use the bitwise shift operator in java, I get a syntax error:

```
class suan {
    int bitCount(int inputInt) {
       if (inputInt == 0)
           return 0;
       else if (inputInt > 0) {
           int c = 0;
           int origin = inputInt;
           for (int i=0; i<32; i++) {
               inputInt=>>1;
               if (origin == inputInt*2)
                   c++;
               origin = inputInt;
           }
           return c;
       } else {   
           return 32-bitCount(-1*inputInt-1);
       }        
    }    
}
```

Eclipse says that "inputInt=>>1" has "Syntax error on token ">>", delete this token.", but I can't see anything wrong with it. I haven't used bitwise operators before in Java, so I might have overlooked some stupid mistake. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try `>>=`. Just like `+=`, not `=+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inputInt=>>1;` should be `inputInt >>= 1;`

Comment: whoops, it was a silly mistake as expected...